# Why I can't left div height to be same right div

Tags: html, css

> In bootstrap, I created two divs inline.
>
> IN right div i have image with property width:100%, now my problem is
>   left div , I want to set his height same of div col-sm-9, how to do
>   that.
>
> Yes easy way is to set height same for col-sm-3 and col-sm-9 but it's
>   not semantic for images. Is it posible to calculate height of col-sm-9
>   and set thats value to col-sm-3?

http://jsfiddle.net/gdxvy575/

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <h2>This is title</h2>
                <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci </p>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <img src="http://eibach.com/sites/eibach.com.m-global/files/pictures/project_cars/eibach_projektfahrzeug_vw_scirocco_1024x768_1.jpg" alt=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
 .col-sm-3{
        height:100%;
        background-color:blue;
        color:white;
        font-weight:300;
    }
    .col-sm-9 img{
        width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: It possible only using`display: table-cell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI now used to **display** **property** `tabel-cell` as like this

```
.col-sm-9, .col-sm-3{display:table-cell;vertical-align:top;float:none;}
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gdxvy575/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the Fiddle here

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdxvy575/3/)

```js
var imgHeight = $('.col-sm-9 img').height();
$('.col-sm-3').css("height", imgHeight);
```

```css
.col-sm-3{
    height:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    font-weight:300;
}
.col-sm-9 img{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h2>This is title</h2>
            <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci </p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <img src="http://eibach.com/sites/eibach.com.m-global/files/pictures/project_cars/eibach_projektfahrzeug_vw_scirocco_1024x768_1.jpg" alt=""/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this